# Pandas dataframe shifting values at certain row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working on a poorly DataFrame.

I am looping through each values in each columns and when a certain value is passed in, I am trying to shift values to the right. For example
[image: original]
this is the dataframe that I am working with and for the 5th column, if the string "Pubmed reference:" is passed I am trying to shift rest of values on the right to shift by certain amount. I saw there is a pandas shift function, but it seems like it moves whole column values by parameter value `period`.

and I would like to change it like this
[image: target format]

what can I do to do this?

Comment: Hi Young, please always post data in text format and not as picture. Considering it is a large dataframe, I would suggest posting a 
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['ORIGINAL_COLUMN'] == "Pubmed reference:"
df.loc[mask, 'TARGET_COLUMN'] = "Pubmed reference:"
df.loc[mask, 'ORIGINAL_COLUMN'] = "NaN"
```

Be sure to replace the column names with your own.